# Using jQuery cookie plugin to save tree state

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery-plugins

In my rails application I have used the jquery.treeTable plugin. I want to save the state of the tree with a cookie. I have downloaded the jquery.cookie.js plugin and in the jquery.treeTable.js, I have modified

```
$.fn.treeTable.defaults = {
    childPrefix: "child-of-",
    expandable: true,
    indent: 16,
    initialState: "collapsed",
    **persist:true,**
    treeColumn: 0
};
```

Please let me know what other changes I have to do to implement cookies.